# How to decode a Hadamard message that was encoded using the inner product method?

Tags: coding-theory

I encoded a message $x = 110$ using the inner product method described on this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_code

**Inner product method**

This method uses the following formula:

$<x,y> = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k (x_i y_i)$ mod $2$

and

$pHad(x) = (<x,y>)_{y \in \{1\} \times \{0,1\}^{k-1} }$

In words: we need to do a "crossproduct mod 2" between $x$ and all possible values of $y$ where $y$ starts with 1, or y = {100, 101, 110, 111}

To calculate $pHad(x)$:

$(1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 0 + 0 \cdot 0)$ mod $2 = 1$

$(1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 0 + 0 \cdot 1)$ mod $2 = 1$

$(1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot 0)$ mod $2 = 0$

$(1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot 1)$ mod $2 = 0$

So the encoded message of $x = 110$ is $pHad(x) = 1100$.

Now my question is, how do I get from the encoded message back to my original message $x$?

EDIT: I have seen the decoding algorithm on the wiki, but I do not understand it. It says I have to pick "j uniformly at random"? This seems like only a way to prove correctness, not an actual algorithm I can use..

Comment: Decoding algorithm usually means a procedure for recovering from errors. Here a decoding algorithm performs the following task. Assume that you transmitted $w=pHad(x)$, but the receiver gets a distorted version $w'$ that differs from $w$ at at most $t=2^{k-2}-1$ positions. Then a decoding algorithm is a procedure for finding $x$ or $w$ (doesn't make much difference) given $w'$ as input.

Comment: Anyway, getting $x$ from $w=pHad(x)$ is easy. The first bit of $w$ is the first bit of $x$, because you used $y=y_1=100000\cdots0$ to get. You can easily locate the bit in $w$ that corresponds to the choice $y=y_j=10\cdots1\cdots0$ (there are two $1$s in this $y$, one at the first position, the second at the $j$th position, $j=2,3,\ldots,k$ Then for all $j>1$
$$x_j=\langle x,y_1+y_j\rangle=\langle x,y_1\rangle+\langle x, y_j\rangle.$$ There are many other ways of doing this.  Your generator matrix is not systematic, so you need some linear equations.